# Open my own app 'Location permission' screen in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, location, settings

I saw that this "Zepp" app call its own app specific Location permission screen which is very handy. The app I manage uses background location for years in its core functions but now in Android >= R this permission have become a little bit of a problem for people that are unexperienced with smartphones.

[image]

Anyone have an idea of how to build an intent to do it?

Comment: You've posted a screenshot of system activity that appears when you request background location permission, does it not appear in your app?

Comment: That screen appears after the user click in the 'manage location settings' label in the Background location permission dialog when the app request this permission, this app I mentioned call an intent that goes directly to that screen, it's way more useful.

Comment: If there's a way to open this activity directly even when location permission is denied that's indeed interesting when you consider how [android 11 changed permission dialog visibility](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#dialog-visibility) and normal permission request won't let you show this activity. So to some extent it looks to be unintended and will probably be disabled in the future.

Comment: I saw Google Fit doing that also